# repetir acciones sin usar for o while?

Tags: javascript

quiero crear un proceso donde un boton ejecute otro , el segundo envie datos a un formulario y se ejecute nuevamente el primer boton que empezo la accion luego de enviarse el formulario

ya cree los botones y les agregue los eventos al ser presionados

```
boton.addEventListener("click", botonpresionado, false);
```

y le agregue un delay para que luego de ser presionado me mostrara en consola que se hizo y se ejecutara el otro paso

```
function botonpresionado() {
  console.log("Se presionó: " + this.id);

    if(this.id=="start"){

    setTimeout(
        function() {
          console.log("en 5segundos te redirecciona...");
            document.getElementsByName("login")[0].click()
        },
        5000);
    }
}
```

¿Alguna idea para que luego de ser enviado el formulario , se redirija a ese boton para empezar nuevamente el ciclo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En lo personal no me queda claro que deseas hacer. Si lo re-planteas sería exclente.

Comment: la editare @ValVert

Comment: mejor? o aun no me explico bien @ValVert

Comment: Otra consulta, ¿cuál es la finalidad de hacerlo así?

Comment: solucionar un problema por pasos, no se si sea la mejor manera, conoces alguna otra forma de hacerlo?  @ValVert

Comment: Hay una instrucción en JS que se llama _debugger_, la cuál detiene la ejecución del programa y te muestra resultados con la ayuda de console.log() en la consola del navegador. Mira este [enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp)

Comment: ¿más o menos a que viene lo de la consola?
aun no se me entiende la duda?
puedes hacer un boton que de click a otro y luego a un tercero de tipo submit y que luego de eso le de click al segundo repitiendo el proceso con un delay?

Comment: _¿más o menos a que viene lo de la consola?_  Si estás solucionando un problema por pasos la consola te ayuda en la visualización de resultados. Según _solucionar un problema por pasos_ entiendo que estas _debugeando_ o no?

Comment: Lo siento, sigo sin entender.

Comment: Podrías poner un setInterval() para que repita la funcion

Comment: no, gracias @amblador. la solucion no hay ,puesto que que js se carga al cargar la pagina lo que me impide hacerlo de esa forma.
lo que hice fue comprobar si un input tenia un valor default al momento de iniciar el primer boton, luego de eso, lanzar el boton 2 con $.#.click de jquery. Ya me hace lo que quiero.

Answer (score 0):

no se cual sea la utilidad para esto:
pero aqui tienes lo solicitado

```js
let contador=0;
async function  botonpresionado(e) {
     contador++;
     console.log(`Se presionó ${contador}: ${e.target.id}`);
     if(contador>=5){alert("ya se a repedito esto 5 veces!"); return;}
        if(e.target.id=="start"){
            await setTimeout(
                async function() {
                    console.log("en 5 segundos te redirecciona...");
                    //document.getElementsByName("login")[0].click();
                    await botonpresionado(e);
            },
            5000);
        }
}


let btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", botonpresionado);
```

```html
<button id="start">presionar</button>
```